# Can zero-length strings be found within a non-zero-length string?

Tags: string

Do non-zero-length strings (e.g. `"foo"`) contain zero-length strings?

In other words, if I search for `""` within `"foo"`, what would be the logical result?

Is it true that there are zero-length strings before the first character, after the last character, and between every two adjacent characters of any non-zero length string?

EDIT 1: Now that I think about it, if the above is true, there could also be more than one zero-length string (even an infinite amount of them) where there could be only one.

EDIT 2:  I'm asking this question from a general perspective (just a simple doubt about the logic behind a formal language). But I want to know if there are fixed rules about this that apply to all formal languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you define the search that way. Different languages and search libraries might or might not do so. Consult the documentation for the language or library that you're using.

If you're writing your own search function, decide how you want it to behave and document it.

As far as I know, most string search operations will match an empty string at the beginning of a non-empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience I would say **Yes** searching for "" would result in all results.  From a DB perspective a `column LIKE '%'` would return all records (assuming NULL's were to be considered "" too)

Comment: This is also true for regexp. However, it's not true for all algorithms/programs that search strings. Some programs use the empty string to mean match nothing. One example is user passwords on unix. An empty user password does not mean that the OS will accept any password - it means the user has no password (depending on configuration this can mean that the user can log in without a password or is forbidden to log in). Another example is Google - it returns nothing for the empty string.

Comment: yes but the question seemed to be *In General*, password searches would make sense to be very specific.

Comment: Google searches would qualify as "general".

Comment: In general, weather or not the empty string match any string or match no string depends on the person who invented the relevant search algorithm. In other words, the answer to this question is **yes** and **no** depending on the programmer.

Comment: I would disagree, **most** filter/grid screens allow you to click `Search` with no criteria, resulting in all results.  You have mentioned some exceptions but in general coding filter/grids allow empty search criteria

Comment: Yep, the question is asked from a general perspective (just a simple doubt about the logic behind a formal language), so I'm not considering `""` and `NULL` to be the same thing.

Comment: @Enorma: It depends, you can define it either way. That's what I'm saying: there's not definite **yes** or **no** answer. It depends on how you define what a string is in your formal language. Regexp just happens to define it one way.

Comment: The OP isn't asking for the exceptions the OP is asking for general acceptance.  Obviously it's up to the person to implement it one way or the other, the REAL question is it common and I would say yes it is common.

Comment: @Enorma, pretty sure my answer is no different than the other "Yes" answers... gimme an upvote man!!! =)

Answer (score 0):

This is going to depend on the language, and what technically defines a string. If a string is theoretically just a sequence of characters with nothing else, then you could find the empty string anywhere, because you could do things like:

```
"foo" === "f" + "" + "oo"
"foo" === "" + "f" + "" + "o" + "" + "o" + ""
```

If you look at how strings are actually implemented, the searching might change. In C, strings are implemented to contain a special character called the null character -- `'\0'` -- at the end of a sequence of characters to mark the end of a string. So `"foo"` is really `'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'` as a character sequence, and so the empty string is actually not truly empty -- it contains the null character as the only character.

With this in mind, searching for strings within other strings is going to depend on whether you want to include the null character in the search. If you do include it, you would only find the empty string at the end of a non-empty string, because you would be searching for a null character in the non-empty string, which would be found at the end. If you don't include it, you would get the same result as above, with the empty string being found anywhere.

Generally though, you don't include the null character in searches. Otherwise `"rob"` would technically not be found in `"acrobat"`, unless it were really `'a', 'c', 'r', 'o', 'b', '\0', 'a', 't', '\0'`

Answer (score 0):

This simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g5najq22/) shows that in java script, the string `"foo"` does indeed contain the empty string `""` and returns true when it is searched for.